# How to find the reaction at the pinned support A as shown in the picture?

Tags: civil-engineering, beam, structures, moments, shear

Please help me solve the problem. I need to know the reactions at A for both the cases as shown. Please note that E is a roller, D is a pin support , B is an internal hinge and A for case 2 is a fixed support.

[image]

Comment: BCDE is rigid and E is a roller?

Comment: @ShareThyThought - Please, share your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: @TigerGuy Yes E is roller, D is a pin support and B is hinged

Comment: @Wasabi, To be precise, I was not getting the reasons for reactions at A to be zero and no its not a homework problem. I am preparing for my University exams

Answer (score 0):

When there are internal hinges on a continuous beam, the first step is to separate the beam into segments at the hinges, then write the equilibrium equations for each segment, and finally solving the equations. For statically indeterminate beams, you should resort to using other methods.

**Case 1)**

[image]

To the left beam segment,

$\sum F_Y = 0, A_Y = B_Y$

$\sum M_B = 0, 5A_Y = 0, A_Y = 0$, thus $B_Y = 0$

Apply $B_Y = 0$ to the beam segment on the right, and solve the reactions on the statically determined beam.

**Case 2)**

[image]

To the left beam segment,

$\sum F_Y = 0, A_Y = B_Y$

$\sum M_A = 0, M = 5B_Y$

To the right beam segment:

$\sum F_Y = 0, B_Y + D_Y - E_Y - 1 = 0$

$\sum M_E = 0, 4B_Y + 2D_Y - 3 = 0$

You can write another global equilibrium equations ($\sum F_Y = 0, \sum M = 0$) on the entire beam, and recognize the fact that $B_Y$ on the left and right of the hinge are equal and opposite to each other, then solving the equations.